# "Access denied finding property 'net.dns*'" (*=1/2/3..) Can't perform TLS network operation on Android Oreo+ devices

Tags: java, android, dns, tls1.2, linphone

When I changed my CompileSDK version to Oreo, Application is not able to perform network operations over TLS protocol on Oreo devices (Android N too). I just get the error message mentioned in the question. 
As stated on official documentations [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#o-pri),

> The system properties net.dns1, net.dns2, net.dns3, and net.dns4 are no longer available, a change that improves privacy on the platform.

I was looking for alternatives to this issue. I do not know very much about network protocols but I just wanted some stuff to surf for this thing like something that let me understand what these things are and why they did this.

Comment: Did you find something for it?

Comment: No brother. I used UDP instead.

Comment: Try adding the following line before making connection, worked for me as it setup DNS lookup mechanism. `AndroidUsingLinkProperties.setup(AppContext.getAppContext());` More information in the following link [https://github.com/MiniDNS/minidns/issues/74] but for me the above line was sufficent.

Comment: Moreover I suggest removing 3 from net.dns3 in the title as it might restrict view for someone searching for similar issue but for net.dns1, net.dns2 etc